# Event to subscribe if I need to log the user's last activity time?

Tags: symfony

I need to log the last user's activity time, every page load or ajax call counts.

I suppose I need to subscribe to some event, But I just have no idea to which one.

InteractiveLoginEvent mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283024), to my understanding is fired in the event of the interactive login only. But, given a session could last a week or more, it will make the record way too inaccurate. So I need another event, but which one?

Or, is there an out of the box functionality for this?

Comment: I don't know of any events that do this.  UserProvider::refreshUser() is called on each request and it's easy enough to plug your own implementation in: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: Thank you, it looks promising. rolling up my own imnplementation is familiar to me, used this approach once overwriting SecurityController

Comment: @YourCommonSense Both answers below don't mention anything about master and sub request. See what [they are](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/zhyb/logging-users-master-and-systems-sub-requests-with-event-listener) and then handle them accordingly in your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be a listener for `KernelEvents::RESPONSE` event, ensuring that the user is authenticated.

```
namespace AppBundle\Subscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class LastActivityListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

        if ($token->isAuthenticated()) {
            // save last activity for $token->getUser(); in some place.
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onResponse',
        ];
    }
}
```

Also, you might need inject the storage service to save this record (e.g. `EntityManager` if Doctrine is available).

Comment: Thank you, looks like exactly what I were looking for!

Comment: @yceruto I like that we both came up with similar but different solutions, and that both work just as well :) Yours works like the 'after' filter and mine works like the 'before' filter from Symfony's documentation.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I implemented this approach. There was one pitfall though. After getting a user entity from `$token->getUser()`, it returns the *string* "anon." when logout button is pressed. I added a condition to circumvent this but it looks weird to me, given `$token->isAuthenticated()` returned **true**.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to subscribe to the `kernel.controller` event, which will run before every controller action, whether normally or via AJAX.  It would look like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class UserActivityLogSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var TokenStorageInterface **/
    private $tokenStorage;

    /** @var LoggerInterface **/
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->logger       = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $actionTime = new \DateTime();
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller) {
            return;
        }

        $action = get_class($controller[0]).'::'.$controller[1];

        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        $user  = $token->getUser();

        if ($user) {
            $logger->info('User: '.$user->getId().' Action: '.$action.' at: '.$now->format('Y-m-d g:i:s');
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        );
    }
}
```

This is just a simple example logging the controller action to your standard logger.  Instead of just outputting to a log, you could inject the **EntityManager** and log the event time to a `last_activity` column in the database for example.

You could also do something like make a **UserLoggableController** controller interface and only perform this action if your controller implements that interface:

**Interface:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

interface UserLoggableController
{
    // ...
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class MyController extends Controller implements UserLoggableController
```

**Modified UserActivityLogSubscriber:**

```
if (!$controller[0] instanceof UserActivityLogSubscriber) {
    return;
}
```

Symfony also has some nice documentation on [setting up controller before/after filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html).

Comment: Thank you for going into much detail. Although I need it for all controllers for now, It does add up to my knowledge and will find it use elsewhere. Looks like there are a lot of possible events but for some were looking in the Security component while indeed for my task it's kernel events which are the best

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't think there's an associated security event for every page/controller load, but @Cerad provides an alternative solution you could try hooking into.